# Batch file to rename files in users APPDATA folder

Tags: batch-file

It appears that all of our users building blocks *.dotx files got corrupted.  I need to rename these files for all users so MS Word recreates them.  Here's what I have put together but it doesn't seem to be working.  I'd like it to go through each users appdata folder (which is stored in R:\Usersfolders\username)and rename these files, appending OLD to the end of the file name.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
@echo off

for /F %Building Blocks.dotx% in(R:\UsersFolders\*username*\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Document Building Blocks\1033\15) do (rename "Building Blocks.dotx" "Building BlocksOLD.dotx")

for /F %Built-In Building Blocks.dotx% in (R:\UsersFolders\*username*\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Document Building Blocks\1033\15) do (rename "Built-In Building Blocks.dotx" "Built-In Building BlocksOLD.dotx")

pause
```

Comment: cared to read the help for `for`? See `for /?`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a few things remarkable wrong.

- you seem to guess the syntax for the `for` command.
- you can't use wildcards in a path (except in the last element)
- your `ren` command has no chance to receive the full path of the file(s)

Your code should look something like:

```
for /f %%a in ('dir /b /ad "R:\UsersFolders"') do (
  echo ren "%%~fa\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Document Building Blocks\1033\15\Built-In Building Blocks.dotx" "Built-In Building BlocksOLD.dotx"
)
```

Comment: Thank You!!  I just tried your suggestion and it is working much better but still not changing the file names.  It appears to be defaulting back to C:\.  This is what is returned as a result of the script.                                                                      
C:\>(echo ren "C:\tcaruso\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Document Building Blocks\1033\15\Built-In Building Blocks.dotx" "Built-In Building
BlocksOLD.dotx" )
ren "C:\tcaruso\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Document Building Blocks\1033\15\Built-In Building Blocks.dotx" "Built-In Building BlocksOLD.
dotx"

Comment: The echo is a security measure, it shows what **would** be executed. If the output looks OK, simply remove the echo.